# Avoid wrapping cause in NoFallbackAvailableException when using Spring Cloud Circuit Breaker

Tags: java, spring, circuit-breaker, spring-cloud-circuitbreaker

I'm using Spring Cloud Circuit Breaker 2.0.0 (resilience4j implementation) for circuit breaking in my application. Let's say a have method define like this:

```java
String doStuff() {
  ...
  // Oh no, something went wrong
  throw new SomethingWentWrongException();
  ...
}
```

I wrap `doStuff` in the circuit breaker:

```java
return circuitBreakerFactory.create("doStuff").run(() -> doStuff());
```

When `SomethingWentWrongException` is thrown, and I haven't declared a fallback for the circuit breaker, then `SomethingWentWrongException` will be wrapped in an instance of `org.springframework.cloud.client.circuitbreaker.NoFallbackAvailableException` as the "cause".

My question is: Is there anyway to configure so that Spring Cloud CircuitBreaker doesn't wrap `SomethingWentWrongException` in `NoFallbackAvailableException` and simply just throws the `SomethingWentWrongException` instead.

Comment: Did you find a way how to do it?

Comment: No, not that I can recall

Answer (score 0):

you can disable the circuit breaker using this property to throw the original exception:

```
spring:
  cloud:
    openfeign:
      circuitbreaker:
        enabled: false
```

but then if you have other fallback classes in your feign clients they are going to stop working.
I would keep it enabled and just provide a fallback to your feign client and then you can handle this more nicely, or check the cause for a source exception.

Comment: docs: 
https://docs.spring.io/spring-cloud-circuitbreaker/docs/current/reference/html/spring-cloud-circuitbreaker-resilience4j.html#_configuring_resilience4j_circuit_breakers


https://docs.spring.io/spring-cloud-openfeign/docs/current/reference/html/#spring-cloud-feign-circuitbreaker-fallback